# Copy subarrays by matching a child key from a multidemensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array similar to this:

```
array(
  array(
    'id'         => 'a',
    'other'      => 'abc: ',
    'subarray' => array(
      'somekey' => 'abc',
    ),
    'subarray2' => array(
      'somekey' => 'abc',
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'id'         => 'b',
    'other'      => 'abc: ',
    'subarray' => array(
      'somekey' => 'abc',
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'id'         => 'c',
    'other'      => 'abc: ',
    'subarray' => array(
      'somekey' => 'abc',
    ),
  ),
  )
```

I need to be able to copy each sub array into a new array by matching the ID. So, let's say I need to match ID 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

The code I ended up using was a foreach loop to loop the array and find my id, then using the key from the parent array to copy the values of the subarray:

```
  $value = 'b'
  foreach ($this->fields as $fields_array => $sub_array) {
    if ( $sub_array['id'] == $value ) {
      $new_array = $this->fields[$fields_array];
      //do something with new array
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is this - answer or addition to a question?

Comment: It's an answer, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this than a foreach loop.